# How to pass value from textbox to label that was on different form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I got an assignment to make a tic tac toe game (size 8*8), so far I manage to code the main game but I got problem on passing value for player names from a newgame form into the mainform, can anyone help?

Code for mainform

```
    public void NameValue1(TextBox NV1)
    {
        lblName1.Text = NV1.Text;
    }

    public void NameValue2(TextBox NV2)
    {
        lblName2.Text = NV2.Text;
    }

private void mnuNewGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        iFlag = 1; // This is used to run the paint function on the form
        StartGame();
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        {
            this._btn[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ClickControl);
            this._btn[i].MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(this.MoveControl); // DEBUG // these 2 allow me to check 'does my mouse hover on the right box?'
            this._btn[i].MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.LeaveControl); // DEBUG //
        }
    }

public void StartGame()
    {
        frmNewGame OpenForm = null;
        OpenForm = new frmNewGame();
        OpenForm.ShowDialog();

        //lblName1.Text = "Player 1"; // PLACEHOLDER // these 2 are what I'm trying to replace to accept values from newgameform
        //lblName2.Text = "Player 2"; // PLACEHOLDER //
        lblName1.Visible = true;
        lblName2.Visible = true;

        Random RandomNumber = new Random();
        int Start = RandomNumber.Next(0, 3);

        if (Start == 1)
        {
            PlayerTurn = "Player1";
            lblName1.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 17, FontStyle.Underline | FontStyle.Bold);
            lblName2.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 17, FontStyle.Regular | FontStyle.Bold);
        }
        else if (Start == 2)
        {
            PlayerTurn = "Player2";
            lblName1.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 17, FontStyle.Regular | FontStyle.Bold);
            lblName2.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 17, FontStyle.Underline | FontStyle.Bold);
        }

        NumberTurn = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        {
            _btn[i].Text = "";
            _btn[i].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            _btn[i].Visible = true;
            _btn[i].Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Code for newgameform

```
public delegate void PassName1(TextBox tbxPlayerName1);
public delegate void PassName2(TextBox tbxPlayerName2);

private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmConnectFour frmGame = new frmConnectFour();
        PassName1 PN1 = new PassName1(frmGame.NameValue1);
        PassName2 PN2 = new PassName2(frmGame.NameValue2);
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
```

As you can see, I already prep the connection between forms to read the player name textbox (no errors), but I got problem on how to pass it to the startgame() function on the mainform

P.S: I can upload the solution if needed

Comment: You are not using your delegates correctly. Call PN1(some_text_box) and PN2(some_text_box) in your event handler after you create your delegates. Having said that, the solution involving properties (below) is much cleaner and better. Delegates are very helpful but don't seem to fit in with your usecase and needlessly complicate matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This subject has been already discussed thousands of times but every time is a bit different.
In this case you could create two public properties in the `newgameform`.
When the user clicks the OK button, you set the properties with the values of the TextBoxes on the `newgameform`.
Then it is easy to read them from the main form.

```
public string Player1 {get; private set;}
public string Player2 {get; private set;}

private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Player1 = txtBoxForPlayer1.Text;
    this.Player2 = txtBoxForPlayer2.Text;
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

and in the main form

```
public void StartGame()
{
    using(frmNewGame OpenForm = new frmNewGame())
    {
        if(DialogResult.OK == OpenForm.ShowDialog())
        {
           lblName1.Text = OpenForm.Player1;
           lblName2.Text = OpenForm.Player2;
           lblName1.Visible = true;
           lblName2.Visible = true;
           .....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I though I can only accept answer once I reach 15 rep points, thanks again :)